# Write a function to compute a**n in C

Tags: c, exponent

Write a function to compute the power a<sup>n</sup>, where n ≥ 0. It
should have the following specification and prototype:

Sets *p to the n’th power of a and returns 0, except
 when n < 0 or p is NULL, in which case it returns -1.

```
int power(int a, int n, int * p);'
```

So far, I am here:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int power(int a, int n, int *p);
  if ( n < 0 || p == NULL)
return -1;
```

Should I use a `for` loop? Or does that not make any sense at all?
I don't know how to calculate a<sup>n</sup> any other way than a * a ... * a.

Comment: Have you tried using a `for` loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Ideally you should submit compilable code in the form of an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Yes, a loop of some sort makes sense.  There's the easy way and the harder way, too.

Comment: The Weekend - Homework time!

Comment: It's also traditional to enclose a function body in braces.

Comment: `a^n` already has a meaning in C; `^` is the bitwise exclusive-or operator. I've updated your title to use `a**n`, which is less ambiguous. (C has no exponentiation operator.) BTW, you should also think about how to handle `0**0` and `n < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a for loop.  It was not clear to me how you wanted to handle erroneous conditions (p is null or n < 0).  The variable 'res' will get overwritten no matter what in this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int a, int n, int *p)
{
        int i;

        *p = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                *p *= a;

        return p == NULL || n < 0 ? -1 : 0;
}

int main()
{
        int res;

        power(4, 2, &res);
        printf("%d\n", res);

        return 0;
}
```